# Double event in arrow-navigating table with input field (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an editable table using jQuery, such that when a user clicks on a cell, an input field appears and the user can enter some text. Special keys are captured to allow saving the text to the cell or otherwise quitting and restoring the previous text.

I now want to allow ARROW keys to be used to quickly move around the table, so that a user can for example enter many consecutive values in the same row by pressing the RIGHT arrow key, without having to mouse-click on each cell one-by-one.

Here is my current code:

```
$( function () {
    $( "td" ).click( function ( event ) {
        if( $( this ).children( "input" ).length > 0 )
            return false;
        var tdObj = $( this );
        var trObj = tdObj.closest( "tr" );
        var tableObj = trObj.closest( "table" );
        var preText = tdObj.html();
        var inputObj = $( "<input type='text' />" );
        tdObj.html( "" );
        inputObj.width( tdObj.width() )
                .height( tdObj.height() )
                .css( { border: "0px" } )
                .val( preText )
                .appendTo( tdObj )
                .trigger( "focus" )
                .trigger( "select" );
        inputObj.keydown( function ( event ) {
            if( 13 == event.which ) { //ENTER
                Update( this, preText );
            }
            else if( 39 == event.which ) {  //RIGHT
                Update( this, preText );
                if( tdObj.index() < trObj.children( "td" ).length - 1 ) {
                    tdObj = tdObj.next();
                    tdObj.click();
                }
            }
            else if( 37 == event.which ) {  //LEFT
                Update( this, preText );
                if( tdObj.index() > 1 ) {
                    tdObj = tdObj.prev();
                    tdObj.click();
                }
            }
            else if( 38 == event.which ) { //UP
                Update( this, preText );
                if( trObj.index() > 1 ) {
                    tdObj = trObj.prev().find( "td:eq(" + tdObj.index() + ")" );
                    tdObj.click();
                }
            }
            else if( 40 == event.which ) {  //DOWN
                Update( this, preText );
                if( trObj.index() < tableObj[0].rows.length - 1 ) {
                    tdObj = trObj.next().find( "td:eq(" + tdObj.index() + ")" );
                    tdObj.click();
                }
            }
            else if( 27 == event.which ) {  //ESC
                tdObj.html( preText );
            }
        } );
        inputObj.focusout( function () { 
            Update( this, preText );
        } );
        inputObj.click( function () {
            return false;
        } );
    } );
} );
```

The called "Update" function does some parsing/validating of the text entered, and restores the original preText in case of failure.

THE PROBLEM:

What doesn't work here, is that when the user enters some text in a cell and then press an ARROW key, the focus moves TWO cells in the chosen direction instead of just one. This does NOT happen if the user presses the arrow keys WITHOUT entering any text, in which case the focus moves correctly one cell at a time.

I think the problem might have to do with calling **tdObj.click()** again, but if I do not this, I cannot automatically open up the next cell's input field;  for example if I use tdObj.focus() instead, the focus is moved correctly to the next cell in the chosen direction, but the user still needs to click on it before being able to enter some text.

I was wondering if calling again **click** might somehow propagate the previous keypress (event.which) to the next calling of this function, thus resulting in one additional step across the table. However if this were true, wouldn't it actually propagate again recursively until the edge of the table is reached? And why doesn't it behave like that if the user *only* presses arrows, without any text?

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

---

UPDATE:

I just noticed that if I implement the whole function for the **.focus **event instead of **.click**, and similarly if I replace all instances of tdObj.click() calls with tdObj.focus() the problem improves partially, as pressing an arrow doesn't cause a double movement across the table.

However the "Update" function is still called twice (I can verify this because if the text fails validation by the Update function, an alert is shown *twice* instead of once). And in addition now, navigating with arrows causes weird changes to the cell borders, and TAB moves one step right + one step down...

Comment: Can you create a working example with relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please provide a complete example, with html, so that we can test this easily. Feel free to create a jsFiddler or something similar.

Comment: I made this fiddle but it's not working... It seems the jQuery function isn't triggered at all, what is the problem here? https://jsfiddle.net/vt31rrqp/3/

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

After trying dozens of changes to the code above, eventually I found out that adding an extra **tdObj.html( preText );** line to each case just before calling the "Update" function got rid of the problem.

Now moving around with arrows works perfectly, and I have absolutely NO IDEA WHY.

I cannot understand the reason why with my original code the "Update" function was always called TWICE, as if there was one more event triggering it. For some reason, now that I first force the .html content of the current cell to have some value before calling "Update", there is clearly only one event. Can anyone explain this behaviour?